# PhotoSwipe not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, photoswipe

I have integrated [PhotoSwipe 4](http://photoswipe.com/) on my website. It works well on a desktop machine when using a mouse, but when I open on mobile nothing works, and I can scroll down (it should close like that). Any ideas why this happens?

Here's a test page with this issue:
http://d9281484.u62.c14.ixinstant.com/events/first-event-2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's caused by mCustomScrollbar script that you're using, which stops the propagation of all touch events on mobile.